# HTML href tags not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I have extracted data from xml using JQM and ajax and I'm trying to create an anchor tag using data extracted dynamically to "hidden" data-role="page" pages.

However my tags/links do not seem to be working.

Code being used is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Jquery mobile</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" 
     href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.5/jquery.mobile- 
     1.4.5.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">

        console.log("starting...");

        var xml;
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "lolcatz.xml",
                    dataType: "xml",
                    success: xmlParser
                    });
                });

        function xmlParser(data) {

        xml=data;

        $(xml).find("kitteh").each(function () {
            kitteh = $(this);
            var name = $(kitteh).find("name").text();
            var src = $(kitteh).find("url").text();

            name=name.replace(/\s+/g, '');

            name = name.charAt(0).toLowerCase() + name.substr(1);

            $("#myList").append('<li><a href="#'+name+'" >'+name+'</div></li>');

            $("#test").append('<li><div data-role="page" id="'+name+'" ><img 
            src='+src+' alt="Image"></div></li>');

             });
        }


</script>

        <div data-role="page">
            <div class="content-primary">
                <div data-demo-html="true">
                    <ul date-role="listview" id="myList" >


                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <ul date-role="listview" id="test">

            </ul>
        </div>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: are you have enoght space between the link and the image for you have to scroll the page? maybe it not scrolled to an image just because it already visible on the page?

Comment: You are creating pages iinside list items. Please, reconsider this kind of design, it doesn't makes sense. As documentation says: a Page is the primary unit of content.

Comment: Hi deblocker, this was the mistake I was making thank you so much for this.